# Speeding up execution of PyQGIS algorithms

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2, performance, algorithm

I don't understand why if I do "manually" some algorithms I get results much faster than when I insert the same in a PyQGIS code (with the same input).
This happens, for example, with the `extract nodes` algorithm.
I wrote a code in which I call the algorithm as follows:

```py
p = processing.runalg("qgis:extractnodes", polylayer, None)

points = processing.getObject(p['OUTPUT'])
```

The whole process slows down considerably during the execution of this algorithm (which appears on the top bar, so I am sure that the problem is right on the `extract nodes`), taking about an hour for provide a result that I would normally be able to achieve in a few seconds.

Comment: which version of Qgis are you using? I had this general issue with Qgis 2.18. I'm not sure whether it is still valid for Qgis3.0.

Comment: Also you might want to take a look at this, about code optimisation : https://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/
(Though here it doesn't seem to be related to your issue)

Comment: I'm using Qgis 2.18 too. Do you think could be a problem?
Thanks for the link: it's not related to my issue directly but it is useful for the future!

Comment: It might, I think there was a bug report about that a few month ago. You might want to look for it, or maybe try it on Qgis 3.0 to see if it's been addressed!

Comment: @Kantan the problem is that if I want use Qgis 3.0 I should change every part of my python code because the new version uses Qt5 and Python 3.x while the last version used Qt4 and Python 2.7